# Find out dependencies for a any .jar bundle

Tags: java, osgi, bundles

I am developing OSGi bundles using Eclipse. I test the code, using an Eclipse OSGi runtime configuration.

The code works fine there, but when I export the bundles as jars and try to use them in another environment (pax-runner, for instance) I get ClassNotFound exceptions at runtime. The bundles are installed fine, with no errors. I execute the command on equinox: "diag bundle-number" and it says: "No unresolved constraints" for every bundle.

I would like to know if there is a tool/method to know, for a given .jar bundle if it needs any external library, which is not described in the manifest.mf.

Comment: Maybe the exception is raised following a call to Class.forName().  It is not possible to predict the classes that will be loaded dynamically.  Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: A jar may contain tons of reference to classes defined elsewhere.  As long as they are not used at run-time, they cannot be considered dependencies.  So be careful about inspecting jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundle will resolve if all the packages listed in `Import-Package` (and the bundles listed in `Require-Bundle`) are found at runtime. If you get `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError` after resolving, it means that the content of `Import-Package` was wrong.

Take a look at the [Bnd tool by Peter Kriens](http://www.aQute.biz/Code/Bnd). This performs static inspection of the bytecode compiled from your classes to discover the exact dependencies, and it generates the `Import-Package` statement for you. In general if you use Bnd, you should never see ClassNotFound/NoClassDefFound unless dynamically load classes by name, e.g. with `Class.forName()`.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss has just release a fantastic Open Source diagnostic tool about dependencies : http://jboss.org/tattletale

One of the features is to analyse the jar files by introspection, to find all lacking dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this a while back (I was cross compiling Java to .NET via IKVM, but needed the dependencies between Jars) I used [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer#What) to create a graph of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with SpringSource's bundlor-shell tool. There are instructions for using it [here](http://www.springsource.org/repository/contribute). You give it a JAR, along with a name and version for the new bundle you want to create from that JAR. It then analyses the class files inside the JAR and produces a template manifest that imports any packages it finds references to.

The hard part is then working out which dependencies are optional, and what version of each package to depend on. You have to read the web site, release notes, etc. for the library to figure this out.

You will get "No unresolved constraints" if the bundle doesn't actually import any packages or require other bundles; as far as the OSGi runtime is concerned, the bundle will be usable. But as soon as it accesses an external class, as in your case, you'll get the dreaded `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Plug-In Development environment (PDE) will give you compile errors if your code uses classes which aren't listed in the MANIFEST.MF. ClassNotFound exceptions at runtime are often caused by incorrectly marking package imports as optional - the bundles resolve, but they won't work. Compiling against a different version of a bundle or package than you're running against could also cause this kind of error.